# Measure latency of remote object read in Redis

Tags: redis, jedis

I have a system of multiple machines, each running a redis server which contains unique objects. A remote client can access each of these servers and read the objects.

I'm wondering to how to measure the latency of a remote read? Can I use Jedis to do it?

Answer (score 0):

One of the tool you usually get when you install Redis, is [redis-benchmark](https://redis.io/topics/benchmarks).
Running a very simple test e.g. `redis-benchmark -n 100000` will get you a very detailed report on the latency.

Here is a snippet of such a report:

```
$ redis-benchmark -n 100000

====== SET ======
  100007 requests completed in 0.88 seconds
  50 parallel clients
  3 bytes payload
  keep alive: 1

58.50% <= 0 milliseconds
99.17% <= 1 milliseconds
99.58% <= 2 milliseconds
99.85% <= 3 milliseconds
99.90% <= 6 milliseconds
100.00% <= 9 milliseconds
114293.71 requests per second
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm interested in the latency of each specific read for experimental purposes

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm interested in the latency of each and every read, I have found SLOWLOG to be useful:
https://redis.io/commands/slowlog

It contains the timestamp and the time it took to process the command.

Comment: Notice slow log only measures the server time and doesn't include the network latency